# How to use custom symbols in mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo

Is it possible to create custom symbols in mapinfo and use it in thematic shading?How?

> Mapinfo - 10.5

Comment: What version of MapInfo are you using?

Comment: @James S  Edited the question

Comment: Is it point symbols you want, or line or polygons?

Comment: @James S It's symbol like triangle etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an old (MI v7.5) article on it.](http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/kbase_by_product/A37A87308D7B8E2085256E450077BC7A).

One slight change will need to be made. If you are using Windows 7 (and possibly Vista) the directory will be something like: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\MapInfo\MapInfo\Professional\1050\CustSymb

Once you have put the file in that folder you will need to restart MapInfo. The symbol should then appear in the symbols list and should be usable on thematic layers as well as normal layers.

**Colourable Symbols**

This is slightly more complicated. [Here's an article on it](http://www.kxcad.net/MapInfo/MapInfo_Professional/MapInfow-17-28.html). Basically you need to save your bitmaps at a lower colour-depth (4-bit seems to work). Then import them as above. Then when choosing your symbol from the list check the "apply colour" box. (If this box is greyed out then try using a different bit-depth.) Once this box is checked any non-white pixels will be coloured with the colour you choose.

Answer (score 1):

[MapInfo User Guide](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/10.5/MapInfoProfessionalUserGuide.pdf) details how to achieve this

Page 167 to 169.